# How do different languages handle the "dangling else"?

Tags: language-agnostic

I often see the dangling else handled as:

```
if (x > 0)
  if (y > 0)
    print "hello"
else
  print "world"
```

the parser or interpreter will actually match the else with the closest if statement, which is the "if (y > 0)".

Does any language have the pitfall of actually matching the else with the outer if or the farthest if?  (except the obvious Python)

Comment: Interesting question, but which one will be the correct answer?

Comment: i think the answer might be: there probably is no language that will match the else with the farthest if.  Some languages make it mandatory that you make it clear by enforcing braces or just use the indentation to indicate which one to match (Python).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short of using space-sensitive languages (like Python, as you said), I don't see why any sensible interpretation would match the outermost `if` block.

Some languages prohibit this potential ambiguity by:

1. Requiring braces for all blocks, and
2. Providing special "else if" syntax, usually `elsif`, `elif`, or `elseif`.

Answer (score 3):

If any language did that (except for the indentation-centric languages), they would have to go into one of the "what is the worst language" lists.

This is also why I almost always use braces for conditionals, and 100% of the time when there are nested conditionals or loops. The few extra characters is worth eliminating the possibility of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, braces are not optional which helps us avoid such issues:

```
if ($x > 0) {
    if ($y > 0) {
        print "hello"
    }
    else {
        print "world"
    }
}
```

versus

```
if ($x > 0) {
    if ($y > 0) {
        print "hello"
    }
}
else {
    print "world"
}
```

IIRC, most C style guidelines require/recommend braces for loops and conditionals.

Answer (score 1):

C# does the "right" thing. Visual Studio's smart indent automatically puts it in the right spot too:

```
if (x > 0)
    if (y > 0)
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("world");
```

This should hopefully be just a theoretical question, since the habit of adding curly's everywhere should be deeply ingrained in most C derivatives, otherwise you're opening up the possibility of nasty surprises.

Comment: visual studio besides indentation, also functionally removes the "ambiguity", by using an 'end if'.  "The problem can also be solved by making explicit the link between an else and its if, within the syntax. This usually helps avoid human errors.  Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else  Possible solutions [to the "ambiguous" dangling else] are:
"Having an "end if" statement. Examples of such languages are ALGOL 68, Ada, Eiffel, PL/SQL, Visual Basic, and Modula-2"     I guess also though it's not that ambiguous since no language seems to interpret it in that other fashion.

Comment: @barlop Indeed, it seems most BASICs that have block if/else have them delimited as IF ... ELSE ... END IF, thereby avoiding any ambiguity.

Comment: What you describe as what C# does is exactly the same as what C does.  Does this mean you think C got it right in the first place and the dangling else 'problem' doesn't need solving?  (I see you've rightly distinguished between what C# does and what Visual Studio does.)

Answer (score 1):

In Python you cannot be ambiguous about it.  Either you have

```
 if (x > 0):
   if (y > 0):
     print "hello"
 else:
   print "world"
```

or

```
 if (x > 0)
   if (y > 0)
     print "hello"
   else:
     print "world"
```

The indentation shows which "if" matches the "else".  [Note:  try as I might, I can't get the "else" in the first example to line up correctly under the first "if".]

In all the languages I have seen that allow this particular ambiguity, the "else" matches with the most recent "if".  That may not be true of all languages that ever existed.  Usually the easiest thing to do when writing the parser is to match up the "else" with the nearest "if" on the stack.

A similar question:  What is the result of 5 - 2 + 1?  Is it 4 or 2?  Personally I always use parentheses when I write (x - y) + z or x - (y + z) because I can never remember which way the parser will go.

Comment: For the last part, IMO it wouldn't make sense for the answer to be 2. Ignoring the order of operations for a second, that would be just backwards. All the languages I've worked with go left-to-right. (Although I guess if the language was designed to be right-to-left then that would make sense, but then the programmer would/should be aware of it.)

Comment: There are 2 ways to interpret 5 - 2 + 1 and they both result in 4

1. 5 + (-2 +1) - combine the -2 and 1 first
2. (5 - 2) + 1 - combine the 5 and -2 first

Comment: You write " I can never remember which way the parser will go." <-- Forget parsers, just learn the standard mathematical convention. Learn BODMAS/PEDMAS properly, it's just basic arithmetic.  Equal priority operators, with no brackets/parenthesis, You parse it left to right. And learn when it makes a difference. You could also look up commutative and associative if you want to get more advanced.

Answer (score 1):

The Way C# works is that it matches the else statements in order of the else statements used.

ie.

```
if (x == 1)
    if (y == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("World");
else
    Console.WriteLine("All your base are belong to us.");
```

however if you want to change where the else goes.

```
if (x == 1)
{
    if (y == 1)
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("All your base are belong to us.");
```

Answer (score 0):

If it didn't match the most recent if, either the whole thing becomes nonsensical or you can't match other ifs.  This (the only real alternative I can imagine) would not make sense:

```
if(first)
    if(second)
        if(third)
            doFirst();
        else
            doSecond();
        else
            doThird();
```

which is just way too wtf.

Answer (score 0):

Most languages will match the `else` with the innermost `if`, and that's really the only reasonable thing for a non-whitespace-sensitive compiler to do.  Many IDEs, as Jeff mentions, will format the code to match the structure, but really, using braces around all code blocks is such a sensible way to deal with this.

Comment: -1  "Most languages will match the else with the innermost " <--- that suggests that you might know of some that don't. And what the questioner was asking was Which languages don't. So you've avoided the question, and you've suggested that some languages take the other interpretation, when quite possibly no languages take the other interpretation.  If you are going to say "Most languages" then you should state at least 1 that does not, otherwise you are misleading.

Answer (score 0):

COBOL, prior to the introduction of the END-IF, rules that the ELSE belongs to the nearest IF.

To else some other than the previous, one has to balance the IFs with the same number of ELSEs. Because there must be an imperative a NEXT SENTENCE clause must be added. As any other case[1] in COBOL the choice of solution seems to the most verbose imaginable.

[1]: EVALUATE WHEN OTHERWISE

Answer (score 0):

In BBC BASIC single line IF statements attach to the next ELSE to the right, with an ELSE potentially shared between multiple IFs.

```
IF A% THEN IF B% THEN PRINT "True" ELSE PRINT "False"
```

Will always print either "True" or "False"